# Что такое критические участки кода? Описание про Коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, терминология

> Хотя это framework, он не имеет явных критических участков кода, и
>   работает как библиотека. (википедия)

Как понять "критические участки кода"?
Как понять "работает как библиотека"?

[Ссылка на термин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Collections_Framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это странный способ сказать что коллекции в яве не потоко безопасны (что не правда).

Статья очень плохого качества. В английской версии про критические участки ничего нет.

Comment: Я как понял эти слова: критические участки кода, мне нужно забыть, да? :)

Comment: В данном конкретном случае их там быть не должно. Сам же по себе "критические участки кода" термин осмысленный. Он связан с многопоточностью, если вы только начали изучение то он вам встретится не скоро.

Answer (score 3):

Формулировка очень сомнительная в любом случае. Попробую объяснить про «работает как библиотека».

[Фреймворком](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA) обычно называют основу программной [платформы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) под которую пишутся приложения.

Как правило, фреймворк/платформа отличается от библиотеки тем, что определяют правила по которым пишется программа. Для того чтобы код работал под фреймворк его нужно писать согласно требованиям: реализовывать определенные классы, объявлять определенные методы.

Например, при написании исполняемой программы под платформу Java нужно объявить класс с методом `public static void main(String[] args)` как точку входа в приложение. При выполнении, платформа обратиться к этому методу.

Иными словами: платформа/фреймворк обращаются к написанному разработчиком коду, в то время как код обращается к библиотекам.

На практике все эти понятия (платформа, фреймворк, библиотека) размываются. Разные источники используют разные определения. Также к путанице приводит то, что программные платформы обычно включают в себя стандартные библиотеки, а библиотеки, в свою очередь, могут быть расширены и использованы как своеобразная основа для разработчика.

В данном случае «работает как библиотека» означает, что Java Collections Framework не ограничивает архитектуру приложения и не определяет никаких требований платформы. По сути, JCF является частью стандартной библиотеки Java.

Можно предположить, что разработчики, давшие название JCF, имели ввиду более широкое определение фреймворка, вроде «набор расширямых библиотек».

P.S. Про «критические участки» кода тоже ничего не понял.